# Low-latency Video Recording

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, html5-video, mediarecorder-api

[image]

The video in the top is the stream from `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` which is set as the source of a the first video element. The bottom  video is the video from `MediaRecorder API`. The video is played from a Virtual Web Camera (*OBS VirtualCam* specifically)

The problem I'm having with this

- When the video starts to stream for the web camera (once allowed) the media seems to be pushed to the `MediaSource` but the playback took a while to actually play (about 2-3 seconds). What kind of behaviour is this?
- Another problem is the playback in the bottom video is delayed, I have been testing and I am finding that the problem is because of the `mediaRecorder.ondataavailable` is not triggered fast enough, thus the chucks are delayed. In what way possible that the MediaRecorder API or similar API can be used to record in much lower latency than this.

**UPDATE:**

What is happening here? 1. Video from camera is play directly in the video element, that element video stream is recorded through MediaRecorder API, recorded video is sent to server (websocket). The video (bottom) is playing the video from websocket. My tests shows that the latency is not from the Websocket but from the either the MediaRecorder or the playback is delayed.

Comment: ...or maybe the playback is the problem, I noticed that glitch at the start of the video where the bottom player started playing late

Comment: Why do you even play what the MediaRecorder records? Yes it will take time, in Firefox it will even buffer for minutes before firing the first dataavailable event, they do need to pack enough data to build a atom that can be pushed to the whole recorded media + they need to compress all that media. But you can simply play the MediaStream that is being recorded. Can't tell why it takes time to receive the first frame, but the MediaRecorder won't fix it anyway.

Comment: It this browser dependent? Firefox notoriously ignores the `frametime` in `recorder.start(frametime)`. Can you show the code that plays video from the web socket?