# Play video blob into Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

How do you play a video blob into a Canvas?

HTML:

`<canvas id="canvas" ></canvas>`

JS:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas")
mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    if (e.data.size > 0) {
       var blob = e.data; // webm video blob chunk
       // how to play this blob into a canvas
    }
}
```

Another use-case

```
setInterval(function(){
   if(frames.length > 0) {
      var webmBlob = Whammy.fromImageArray(frames, frameRate); // webm video
      // render webm video blob into Canvas
   }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: That's not a video but a chunk of a video, you need to concatenate it with other chunks, and to play it through a video. Literally all examples about the MediaRecorder on the web show how to do that. But if you want to pass it to the canvas, why even bother using a MediaRecorder? Play the original stream instead...

Comment: @Kaiido the reason is for Low-latency recording and playback that I am trying to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051566/low-latency-video-recording

Comment: ... Then let's move to that other question, this one is really just about a "Z" in an X-Y problem.

Comment: I believe this is a valid question "How to Play video blob into Canvas" which apparently as I was trying to do it, it's quite hard

Comment: No it's not hard at all, you just need to learn the basics of what you are trying to do, but fine, I'll post an answer if you really want to, but that's really not what you should do!

Comment: I updated the post with a better use case

Answer (score 3):

What your MediaRecorder's `ondataavailable` outputs is not a video blob, it's only a chunk of a video file. Except for the very first one, it can't be played alone, you need to concatenate it with all the previous chunks that have been recorded until then.

```
const chunks = [];
recorder.ondatavailable = (evt) => {
  chunks.push( evt.data ); // store all the chunks
  play( new Blob( chunks ) ); // concatenate all the chunks to as single Blob
};
```

Then to play a video served as a Blob, you have to create an URL pointing to that Blob, this is done using the `URL.createObjectURL()` method.

Now, to draw it on a canvas, you must pass through a <video> element, on which you'll set the `src` to the blob: URI we created right before:

```js
(async () => {

  const source = document.createElement( 'video' );
  source.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  source.muted = true;
  source.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm";
  console.log('loading, please wait');
  await source.play();
  
  const player = document.createElement( 'video' );
  player.muted = true;
  const output = document.getElementById( 'output' );
  const ctx = output.getContext( '2d' );
  
  const stream = (source.captureStream && source.captureStream()) || source.mozCaptureStream();
  const recorder = new MediaRecorder( stream );
  const chunks = [];
  recorder.ondataavailable = (evt) => {
    console.clear();
    chunks.push( evt.data );
    play( new Blob( chunks ) );
  };

  console.clear();
  console.log('buffering, please wait 5s');
  recorder.start( 5000 ); // 5s per chunk
  
  source.addEventListener( 'ended', (evt) => recorder.stop() );
  
  function play( blob ) {

    if( player.paused ) {
      drawing = true;
      player.addEventListener( 'loadedmetadata', (evt) => {
        output.width = player.videoWidth;
        output.height = player.videoHeight;
        requestAnimationFrame( loop );
      }, { once: true } );
    }
    player.src = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
    player.play();

  }
  function loop() {
    ctx.drawImage( player, 0, 0 );
    if( !player.paused ) {
      requestAnimationFrame( loop );
    }
  }
  
})().catch( console.error );
```

```html
<canvas id="output"></canvas>
```

But note that it's really **not a common thing to do...**

We normally do wait for the whole recording is done before doing anything with the resulting video file:

```
const chunks = [];
recorder.ondatavailable = (evt) => {
  chunks.push( evt.data ); // store all the chunks
};
recorder.onstop = (evt) => { // only when the recording is entirely done
  play( new Blob( chunks ) ); // concatenate all the chunks to as single Blob
};
```

But if you really want to draw that video on the canvas in real-time, just do this and don't use a MediaRecorder at all:

```js
(async () => {

  const source = document.createElement( 'video' );
  source.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  source.muted = true;
  source.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/BBH_gravitational_lensing_of_gw150914.webm";
  console.log('loading, please wait');
  await source.play();
  console.clear();
  
  const player = document.createElement( 'video' );
  player.muted = true;
  const output = document.getElementById( 'output' );
  const ctx = output.getContext( '2d' );
  
  const stream = (source.captureStream && source.captureStream()) || source.mozCaptureStream();

  player.addEventListener( 'loadedmetadata', (evt) => {
    output.width = player.videoWidth;
    output.height = player.videoHeight;
    requestAnimationFrame( loop );
  }, { once: true } );
  player.srcObject = stream;
  player.play();

  function loop() {
    ctx.drawImage( player, 0, 0 );
    if( !source.paused ) {
      requestAnimationFrame( loop );
    }
  }
  
})().catch( console.error );
```

```html
<canvas id="output"></canvas>
```

Comment: I already have this code, in fact, similar that I have a video element as source then it is drawn to the canvas via that `requestAnimationFrame`, so I am way past this issue hence I was able to capture the frames from the canvas and store it in `Whammy.fromImageArray(frames, frameRate);` which I have updated my post. This whammy method returns an actual webm video itself which I tested to manually download and it plays. The reason I want to "play blob in a canvas" is to test the generated blob if when played in the correct FPS, etc.

Comment: Read the answer again. All is there.

Comment: I have been testing your code and I found the issue with your solution. It assumes the webm as a static resource. In my case the webm blob is generated dynamically at 1 second interval inside a `setInterval`